# How to stop Ubuntu keeping writing degraded RAID

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have a hardware RAID (Adaptec 5805, RAID 6 of eight 6TB drives) that recently constantly fails when I have lots of disk writes. I installed Ubuntu on a separate disk and the Ubuntu seems not able to stop me writing when the RAID becomes suboptimal or degraded. Therefore when I found the array became unrecoverable, it was already too late.  This happened twice after I rebuilt the RAID and during copying data back.

I guess the problem of RAID failure is due to unstable power supply.  However, before I figure out the source of the power issue, what settings can I tune to allow the RAID to alert the system so that it can remount the array to read-only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't.  That's kinda the whole point of RAID: that the OS *doesn't* know that a single drive has failed, and can keep happily chugging along.

I guess you could wire up something to the `mdadm --monitor` command to run a custom script on degrade events that did a `mount -o ro,remount /dev/md/N`, but that seems like putting lipstick on the pig.  You should be running a RAID level and configuration that isn't as susceptible to rebuild errors.  I'm thinking you've probably got large spinning-platter disks and are using RAID-5?  That's what we in the business call, "a recipe for disaster".  You're gonna have a bad time.  Use RAID-6 (at the very least) and have spare disks on hand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't know much about mdadm.  Isn't it for software RAID?  Though I found there is Adaptec Event Monitor and maybe that can somehow alert the system to remount the RAID.

Comment: And a good script that can send email when the RAID has problem.  That may serve my purpose for now.  Thanks for the facts that RAID is designed for transparent data access!  http://www.neant.ro/2013/02/monitoring-adaptec-raid-arrays-with-arcconf/